# Activiti: How to save the user who has suspended an Activiti process instance on Activiti DB

Tags: java, activiti

I am working with Activiti API and, in my project, I have a panel which allows the users to suspend a process instance. In order to make this suspension, I am following the steps listed [here](http://www.activiti.org/userguide/#_activate_or_suspend_a_process_instance), however I would like to save somehow the logged user who has suspended the process, is it possible?

I have already a String with the user in my code, but I don't know how could I save it on Activiti data base as the user who has suspended the process instance.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the UI you are using to call "suspend", you should call the API to create a process variable with the userId THEN call suspend.

The API to create a process variable is here: http://www.activiti.org/userguide/#_create_or_update_variables_on_a_process_instance

Comment: Harley, thanks for your comment. I think it is a good solution for the problem. I also need to store the user who has upload a new workflow, so as we don't have variables in this case, do you have any ideia how could I do it?

Comment: Ahh, keeping a record of who published (uploaded) a deployment is harder as the information is not tracked.
In the past, we have handled this in one of two ways:

1. Overloaded the tenantId with the userid (if you dont have multiple tenants it is safe).

Comment: 2. Maintained an external metadata store (Database table) with a foreign key to the deployment ID that includes the userID.
3. Add a resource file the the deployment package by extending the DeploymentManager